# Vaadin: Anchor sets internal URL in browser but does not navigate

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

In a LoginView in a Vaadin 23.1.0 application I've got an `Anchor` to navigate to Microsoft Azure Login URL: `add(new Anchor("/oauth2/authorization/azure", "Login with MS Azure AD"));`.

**Problem**: When I click that anchor / link then the URL in the browser (Firefox 101.0.1 and also Chromium 103) updates to `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/azure`, but the browser does not navigate.

**Question**: How can I get that anchor to navigate to the given target?

**What I tried**:

1. When I click the anchor and then hit F5 it just works fine. (This is the workaround for the moment. And it shows that the URL is reachable.)
2. When I change the `href` of that `Anchor` e.g. to "https://google.com", then it navigates.

**Additional observations:**
When I click the anchor, there is a request from the browser to the Vaadin server with this request: `{"csrfToken":"10c44508-3e55-455c-b4b1-86b7d2390f44","rpc":[{"type":"publishedEventHandler","node":1,"templateEventMethodName":"connectClient","templateEventMethodArgs":["flow-container-root-2521314","ROOT-2521314","oauth2/authorization/azure","",null],"promise":4}],"syncId":4,"clientId":4}` and with this response:
`for(;;);[{"syncId":5,"clientId":5,"execute":[["Systemanmeldung","document.title = $0"],["Systemanmeldung","document.title = $0"],[false,[0,3],"return (function() { this.serverConnected($0)}).apply($1)"],[4,null,[0,1],"return (function() { this.$server['}p']($0, true, $1)}).apply($2)"]]}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `anchor.getElement().setAttribute("router-ignore", true);` if you need your service to handle the given URL instead of the client-side router.

Comment: Works like a charm! :-) Seems that I ignored this when migrating from Vaadin 14 to Vaadin 23 ( https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/upgrading/essential-steps/#miscellaneous-changes )...

Comment: Seems like this should be part of the API.