# I can't create an external link (href) that open itself without the localhost:8080 in front of it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm trying to create a link (href) that open itself in a new page. Should be "simple".

That's the focus code:

```
if (propertybox.getValue(CandidatoLink.LINK) != null) {
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor(propertybox.getValue(CandidatoLink.LINK),
            propertybox.getValue(CandidatoLink.LINK));
    anchor.setTarget("_blank");
    return anchor;
}
```

This is to get the link from the database, like "www.google.com":

```
propertybox.getValue(CandidatoLink.LINK));
```

This is to get the link opening in a new tab of the browser:

```
anchor.setTarget("_blank");
```

It works all just fine: I can get the link opened in a new tab. The only problem is that the system think that's an intern page of the website and sees it as a Route! That's the problem. It will open a new tab with this link: http://localhost:8080/www.google.com

I can't remove the first part (http://localhost:8080/). Can someone help me?

I use Java 11.0.15, Vaadin 14 (Maven/Spring Boot) and my IDE is Eclipse 2022-06 (4.24.0).

Comment: `"http://" + propertybox.getValue(CandidatoLink.LINK)`?

Comment: Or probably https://

Comment: Did you try `anchor.getElement().setAttribute("router-ignore", true);`? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727825/vaadin-anchor-sets-internal-url-in-browser-but-does-not-navigate)